# ostream: how are functions being called for this chained output?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain how the following iostream `cout` code is evaluated with each specific function including its declaration?  Also, how the `hex` manipulator modifies the stream flags (my guess is it calls `ios.flags()`).  For instance, I'm looking at [ostream member functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) and [non member functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) and am confused on what is being called and the order of evaluation (I think there is no specified order).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int v = 0xFF;
    cout << "0x" << hex << v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing your specific environment, the best anybody here could do is guess the actual calls being made.  Your best option is probably to use a debugger and step through the code, including stepping into functions.  The order of evaluation is well-defined though (equivalent to `(((cout << "0x") << hex) << v) << endl`).

Comment: It's only well defined from c++17 though.

Comment: @StephenNewell based on this my suspicion is `ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s)` is first called returning an &ostream object, then `std::ostream::ostream& operator<< (ios& (*pf)(ios&))` is called returning a &ostream with flags modified, then `std::ostream::ostream& operator<< (int val)`, .... does that make sense?

Comment: @notaorb yes, that is exactly what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::hex` and `std::endl` are standalone functions that take a `std::ios_base&` and `std::basic_ostream&` as input, respectively:

```cpp
std::ios_base& hex( std::ios_base& str );
```

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

These functions manipulate the given stream as needed:

- `std::hex()` calls the stream's `setf()` method to enable the `std::ios_base::hex` flag on it.
- `std::endl()` writes a line break to the stream and then flushes the stream.

`std::basic_ostream` has non-static member `operator<<` overloads which take those kind of functions as input:

```cpp
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );
```

```cpp
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

These `operator<<` overloads simply call the given function with `*this` as input, and then return `*this` to the caller.

There is also a non-static member `operator<<` overload for taking an `int` as input:

```cpp
basic_ostream& operator<<( int value );
```

This overload writes the `int` value to `this`, and then returns `*this` to the caller.

However, there is no non-static member `operator<<` overload for taking a string literal as input, but there are standalone non-member `operator<<` overloads for that:

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                         const CharT* s );
```

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                         const char* s );
```

```cpp
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,  
                                        const char* s );
```

These overloads write the `char*` data to `os`, and then return `os` to the caller.

So, the expression:

```cpp
cout << "0x" << hex << v << endl;
```

Ends up being evaluated like this:

```cpp
operator<<(cout, "0x").operator<<(hex).operator<<(v).operator<<(endl);
```